# Exporting mysql database to csv through php stops after 4kb

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am using a script which is designed to pull tables out of a database and format them to csv and save to you machine.

It works fine and all but as soon as the file hits 4kb it stops and saves.

Obviously the table is larger than 4kb so it gets cut off mid sentence.

I'm thinking a memory allocation issue? any ideas as to what might cause this?

running apache

Comment: with out seeing the script, no one can help.

Comment: could be a run-time error (your script needs more time to run than you allow in http.conf or in the script itself) try on top of your script : ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

Comment: nothing to do with with the script. please re-read and its always an even 4kb which is highly unlikely to be a runtime thing.

Comment: what is your memory limit looks like memory issue try this ini_set('memory_limit','32M');

Comment: if you have really huge database then you need to increase max exec time as well

Comment: its only about 20-25 rows with about 12 columns. small amounts of data. fairly small really

Comment: everything to do with the script, but if you want to be that way, this is the help you get.

Comment: What does your error log say?

Answer (score 2):

PHPMyAdmin and this stuff have many problems when you try tu export your DB (buffer limitations...).

To export your MySQL data you could try mysqldump: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

This way:

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p[user_password] [database_name] > backup.sql
```

PS: be careful because -p paramater goes without a white space.

Comment: That will work but the idea was to create a CSV which we can use to import to our other software packages, if its a buffer limitation can this be lifted in php.ini?

Comment: you can get it by appending --fields-terminated-by=',' to your mysqldump line (Comma as separator)

Comment: The scrip deals with extra commas in the database that would normally throw off the CSV format. This process has to be idiot proof and to do this would require manually editing the file to remove the extra commas (allot of people tend to use commas when entering their address)

Comment: When you use mysqldump MySQL put quotes before and after the VARCHAR, so shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: ok great. will try this one then. Had hoped to use this script for use with product descriptions too but i'll just have to find something else.